# Get a list of all running applications

Tags: android

I want to get a list of all currently running applications (also paused applications in the background).

I can only find old answers to the problem with a deprecated api (ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()), which does not work anymore.

I have tested the following code:

```
public class TaskManager {
    private static final String TAG = "TaskManager";

    private ActivityManager manager;

    public TaskManager(ActivityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public void getRunningApps() {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningApps = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningApp : runningApps) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getRunningApps: " + runningApp.processName);
        }
    }
}
```

which unfortunately only returns the process name of the application i'm calling it from.

Is there any way to get a running application list in Android 5.0+ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

Log.i("current_app",tasks.get(0).processName);
```

Comment: This will only give me my own app. But i need all apps that are running.

Comment: you want the package name or the activity name?

Comment: the package name would be perfekt i think.

Comment: It returns only my app, even I did a server that checks every minute and change the foreground app (My app is a kiosk)